# Access an element outside of the target

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery Cookie to store values from a clicked element (link element with a flag image as background), that once clicked, it will change the HTML in a different target location.

For example, below I'm trying to target `a.flag`, and then set a cookie that targets `a.nturl`, then finds the first `img` tag within it and outputs the `src` of that image element:

```
$("a.flag").click(function(event) {
    location.reload();
       $.cookie("language_name", event.target.id, { path: "/" });
       $.cookie("flag_url", $("a.nturl").find("img").attr("src"), {path: "/" });       
});
```

Then here's the function that retrieves cookies and outputs them in HTML:

```
 $(function() {
               var language_name = $.cookie("language_name");
               var flag_url = $.cookie("flag_url");
                  if (language_name === "English"){ 

                  $("div.selected").html( "<a onclick=\"return false;\" href=\"#\"><span><img src=\"" + flag_url + "\" alt=\"English\" height=\"16\" width=\"16\"></span>" + language_name + "</a>");  

               }
```

For some reason, the `flag_url` cookie is not storing values properly - it's currently storing only the first `src` attribute from `a.nturl`.

The code below seems to work great when performing actions within the target itself using  `$(this)`:

```
$("a.nturl").click(function(event) {
   location.reload();
               $.cookie("language_name", $(this).attr("title"), { path: "/" });
               $.cookie("flag_url", $(this).find("img").attr("src"), {path: "/" });

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do stuff with session before calling the page reload so you should write :

```
$("a.flag").click(function(event) {
    $.cookie("language_name", event.target.id, { path: "/" });
    $.cookie("flag_url", $("a.nturl").find("img").attr("src"), {path: "/" });       

    location.reload();
```

});